# xterm.js basic demo not working

Tags: node.js, xtermjs

So, I am trying to create a website which has a terminal embedded in it and am using xterm to do this. so far, ive been learning xterm and trying to get the basics to work, but i've been having difficulty. Here is the code for the terminal below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Mohammad Nadeem</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/xterm/dist/xterm.css" />
   <script src="node_modules/xterm/dist/xterm.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div id = "terminal">
   </div>
   <script type = "text/javascript">
    import { Terminal } from 'xterm';
    var term = new Terminal();
    term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'), true);
    term.fit();
    term.writeln('Hello World!');
   </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to using `import` (ES6 Modules) when add library via script tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Mohammad Nadeem</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/xterm/dist/xterm.css" />
   <script src="node_modules/xterm/dist/xterm.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div id = "terminal"></div>

   <script type = "text/javascript">
      var term = new Terminal();
      term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
      term.writeln('Hello World!');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to using addon like `fit`, you must import it, example:

```
<script src="node_modules/xterm/lib/addons/fit/fit.js"></script>
```